# Magento Product Stock status changes automatically

Tags: magento, magento2, stock

We are facing a issue in Magento 2.4. We are using MSI and we have 3 warehouses. All products have assigned 3 warehouse and we manage stock using MSI. A product can be available on one warehouse and can't be available on another, The issue is when we get product out of stock one day it get automatically in stock after 1 or 2 days and its random behavior not with specific products or warehouse.
Initially we thought may be its done by someone in team if they worked on same product so we have setup an alert when ever product get changed by admin we get notification on Email. But the strange thing is without any alert still status get changed.

I have used this event `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after`   to trigger an alert when ever product get changed and its working as well we have tested it.

Although we have restrict import functionality for other users, but we think product may be changed through csv or api although we have restricted but may be it can be done from any user.

Can any one please help if someone faced similar issue or any model function which always trigger when ever product stock status get changed from any action like API or from CSV or from Admin Edit or even frontend ??

Comment: I think it is likely the MSI module. Can you check if it is because if any warehouses get out of stock and it changed the status for product? Because in magento, the stock can only be global scope.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Magento event catalog_product_save_after. Create an observer method that does the following on event catalog_product_save_after.

```
public function catalog_product_save_after($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $stockData = $product->getStockData();

    if ( $product && $stockData['qty'] ) {
        $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getEntityId()); // Load the stock for this product
        $stock->setData('is_in_stock', 1); // Set the Product to InStock                               
        $stock->save(); // Save
    }
}
```